# storing user created data

Tags: html, database, storage

So I've looked into databases, but am a little questionable about what they really are. I think they are a place to store information a user inputs (like this question), but everything about them seems allot more complicated than that. My question is, how would i store a simple document users create? Would i use a database? is there a way I can just make a folder and tell the website to save the user created file to that folder? Is there a different way i should do this?

The data I want to store is a user created "card" which i would probably use a txt file with a bunch of numbers to give all of the information to another player. Is this a good way to store variables like this? Am i thinking the right way on how to do this? and how, code wise might I go about saving this data to a folder or database and retrieving it? I'm happy to give any more information, but I'm a little clueless right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can store data in organized file structure, but there are certain advantages that you get out of using databases not that would depend on what kind of database you are using relational, object driven etc.

1)Constraints and checks to maintain data integrity, in file system you have to do it all on your own.

2)I assume your user created data has multiple fields, and in this case if you have to query based on values in these fields you have to scan each file and do the scanning.

Whereas if you have database there are languages like sql to make it easier for you.

3)If you want this database to be shared amongst multiple applications on network you have to provide access to the folder containing these files.

What you can do is analyze your need, find out Pros/Cons of each of them and use mix of DB/File System/FTP. You can find many ways of doing any of this on internet. To address it in this space is pretty hard.

Comment: thanks, i definitely will keep looking into databases. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use databases for store users files, like documents. But this files will not store into the database directly, only path like in example:

```
CREATE TABLE Files (
id       SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
filename VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
filesize INT         NOT NULL,
data     BYTEA       NOT NULL,
created  TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
... other metadata ...
```

);

But anyway the better way to save information about player is database of course, not txt file.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
id       SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
name     VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
age      INT         NOT NULL,
... other metadata ...
```

);

Comment: yeah, ill keep looking into databases, thanks for the response.